# blazor- create subpage path extension like "~/product/{itemId:int}/edit"

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

**The title need to be changed**; Because I don't know how to describe my problem.
 Lets say we have this pages:

```
localhost:5000/counter
localhost:5000/products/{itemId:int}
localhost:5000/employee/{userId:int}
```

The idea is to create a universal subpage "**/Edit**" like:

```
localhost:5000/counter/Edit
localhost:5000/products/{itemId:int}/Edit
localhost:5000/employee/{userId:int}/Edit
```

The page should lode as it was but with places to edit that specific (item, user or the parameter) in the page.
Another example could be "**/Report**"
**The main goal is that the page base url do not change!** => This is not okey
<del>`localhost:5000/Edit/user/{userId:int}`</del>.

 The main problem that I'm getting is that I can't add parameters before the subpage-Extension. Repeated code to check the url in every page will be pain.

 I'm making my website like File-Explorer, the path is like this:

```
localhost:5000/Folder/{path:string}

// will show => list of folders and files
//     
//        or => a file => ImgeFile-view  component
//                     => PdfFile-view   component
//                     => wordFile-view  component
//                     => video.....
```

Each component have it's own properties even the folder. so if i'm logged-in as admin and i add **/edit** to the end of any url i need to be able to edit the content and send it back to the DB.

 Next step will be to change the (html or blazor) tags to input with the tags id and interface's.

Please comment with your ideas or objections.

Comment: Pages don't really exist in SPAs.  In your context which component loads for route `localhost:5000/products/{itemId:int}/Edit` and which loads for `localhost:5000/employee/{userId:int}/Edit`?  Or is `Edit` really just a state?   PS - I would remove that last line, it's not helpful, I almost passed you by - others likely will.  I don't particularly care what PHP can or can't do!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis yes, Edit is a page state! where it shift the components of the page to EditForm. I'm thinking to store the tags that i can edit in a `RenderFragment` and switch it there? Sorry for that last line but i thought that it will be a boost! c# in blazor is like PHP for me and i believe it is.

Comment: NP - will come back with an answer later :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't so it with the current router.  You need to write your own router (not a trivial task),  or change your strategy - for example a querystring `localhost:5000/products/{itemId:int}?state=edit` will work.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis exploring how to make a custom router sounds fun, do you have anything that will help me start with it?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> exploring how to make a custom router sounds fun, do you have anything that will help me start with it?

The .Net Core `Router` code is here in the aspnetcore Github repository - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/Routing/Router.cs.

It's not that easy to lift "as is" because a lot of the support classes are internal assembly classes.  You'll have to copy and refactor a lot of classes to get it running.

I've already written a custom router, so done the work.  Your welcome to lift the code.  You can find everything in a Github repo here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.EditForm.

The actual library detail is here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.EditForm/tree/master/Blazr.NavigationLocker

Comment: indeed it is; time now to research and learn. thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question but you can have multiple paths for one page. On the Edit page include all three paths;

```
@page "/counter/Edit"
@page "/products/{itemId:int}/Edit"
@page "/employee/{userId:int}/Edit"

(Edit Page Markup)

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int itemId { get; set; } 

    [Parameter]
    public int userId { get; set; } 
}
```

You don't need to check the url in every request. It's a bit yucky but if `itemId` and `userId` are both 0 than you know your in counter. If `itemId` is greater than 0 you know your in products and if `userId` is greater than 0 you know your in employee.

Comment: this way i have to add the same code to each view component, and the page will get longer and longer. i have added my work example, maybe it more clearer?